# Convert angles from the sexagecimal system to centesimal one

Tags: arithmetic, unit-of-measure

> How do you convert angles from the sexagecimal system to centesimal one?

For example

63 degrees 14 minutes 51 seconds reduced to centesimal ??

Here's how it's done but I don't understand the steps:  [image at postimg](http://postimg.org/image/4tat51y63/)

Comment: What is centesimal?

Comment: base 100 system (opposed to base 60 that we use in time)

Comment: In mathematics, we measure angles in radians. Base $100$ is *essentially* the same as base $10$, just like hexadecimal is essentially the same as binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you convert the measurement to purely degrees. There are 60 seconds per minute and 60 minutes per degree.

So $51$ seconds is equal to $\frac{51 \textrm{sec}}{60 \textrm{sec/min}} = 0.85 \textrm{min}$ . Your angle can now be written as: 63 degrees, 14.85 minutes.

Converting 14.85 minutes to degrees, we again divide by 60:

14.85 minutes is $\frac{14.85 \textrm{min}}{60 \textrm{min/deg}} = .2475 \textrm{deg}$. Your angle is now written as: 63.22475 degrees.

Convert one more time by the appropriate constant.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

I write the conversion factors so that it looks clearer:

$$51'' = 51'' \cdot \frac{1'}{60''} = \left(\frac{51}{60}\right)' = \left(\frac{17}{20}\right)' = 0.85'$$

So,

$$14'51'' = 14.85' = 14.85' \cdot \frac{1^\circ}{60'} = 0.2475^\circ$$

and thus,

$$63^\circ 14'51'' = 63.2475^\circ = 63.2475^\circ \cdot \frac{1 \text{ rt. angle}}{90^\circ} = 0.70275 \text{ rt. angle} $$
$$= 0.70275 \text{ rt. angle} \cdot \frac{100^g}{1 \text{ rt. angle}}= 70.275^g$$